# Cortex M7 floating arithmetic instruction duration with zero operand

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, stm32

I'd like to know whether the duration of a floating point instruction like VMUL is significantly shorter when an operand is zero, on a Cortex M7 FPU.

The reason is that I'm profiling a software that is processing many variables coming from analog sources, and more precisely the evolution of these variables with time. But right now the "front end" (ie. the analog sources) is not available so I'm using simulated variables but since they are not evolving with time, many variables in the code are zero.

Comment: The only realistic way I can see of you getting a meaningful answer is to profile it yourself.

Comment: @ThomasJager: Or one could download the processor manual from ARM and examine the timing information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As far as I'm aware, ARM doesn't publish M7 cycle tables.

Comment: I'd be *very* surprised if the latency for `0.f*x` were *faster* than other operands. Even the smaller cortex-m's have single-cycle 32-bit integer multipliers, and a `float`-multiplication is almost certainly fairly easy to do in 2-3 cycles if your 23-bit mantissas can be multiplied in a single cycle. It would make no sense whatsoever to complicate the instruction for basically no gain, increased complexity and worse determinism. The only exception might be denormal results from multiplying normalized numbers, but I'd expect a microcontroller to flush to zero instead of taking variable latency

Comment: Even if there were tables which it wouldnt make sense there would be.  You would still want/need to profile it on that chip/system.  directed bare metal tests, caches off,  run from ram, be in control of the wait states on the memory if any, faster clock speeds are often bad for this kind of work and question, want the minimal wait states on the memory if you are going after the cores performance.  not uncommon for the flash to have a cache that you cannot control as well as often starting with one instruction every other clock compared to sram.

Comment: I know from the arm docs that some of the cores can be compiled for fast multiplies or slower multi-clock ones I assume that the fpu would also have similar options as multiply and divide all by themselves can dominate your chip footprint as you try to implement them with fewer clocks.

Comment: @EOF For the record I already profiled (few weeks ago) a loop of thousands of vmul. In double precision, in average (with cache enabled, execution from flash) each vmul was taking around 6 cycles.I understand your point about hardware complexity, it makes sense.

Comment: @old_timer very interesting. It means that different products embedding the same ARM core may have different performance regarding instruction timing ? Good to know.

Comment: with a pipeline its not easy to predict the performance.  all other things held constant including the cache, multiple runs on the same system of the same code can perform the same (does depend on the cache design).  The same code on different systems may very well perform differently is the issue because arm's logic is only a portion of the equation, the chip vendors and chip family and other factors play a role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipelined CPUs usually have fixed latencies (not data-dependent) for everything except very slow operations like `div`.  Otherwise you have to deal with write-back conflicts if you start a "fast" instruction a cycle or two after a "slow" instruction.

You could test it yourself by running the `vmul` in a latency-bound loop (e.g. multiply a register by itself 3 or 4 times in an unrolled loop).  Try with "simple" values like `0.0`, then with non-simple values like `1.0000000001` (which has many significant digits).  Run enough loop iterations to hide measurement overhead, but few enough that you stop before overflow to +Inf.

Answer (score 0):

So I've fought my laziness and did a profiling myself :)

Here is the code of the function I used to execute a loop of double precision vmul on a STM32H753, with GCC (options FPv5-D16, -mfloat-abi=hard, -Ofast):

```
void __attribute__((noinline))
asmMulDsimple(double a, double b) {
  asm volatile( "vmul.f64 d2, d0, d1 \n"
                "vmul.f64 d2, d0, d1 \n"
                "vmul.f64 d2, d0, d1 \n"
                ...
                ( 100 times )
                ...
                "vmul.f64 d2, d0, d1 \n"
               : [a] "+&r"(a), [b] "+&r"(b)
               :
               : "cc", "memory", "r12");
}
```

And the calls in the main (`Reset_Cycle_Counter` and `Get_Cycle_Counter` are basic functions to use DWT_CYCCNT cycle counter) :

```
    Reset_Cycle_Counter();
    {
        asmMulDsimple(1.00000001, 2.0000000004);

        printf("Duration with 100 vmul, complex operands: %lu cycles\r\n", Get_Cycle_Counter());
    }


    Reset_Cycle_Counter();
    {
        asmMulDsimple(1, 2);

        printf("Duration with 100 vmul, simple operands: %lu cycles\r\n", Get_Cycle_Counter());
    }

    Reset_Cycle_Counter();
    {
        asmMulDsimple(0, 2.0000000004);

        printf("Duration with 100 vmul, 0 operands: %lu cycles\r\n", Get_Cycle_Counter());
    }
```

And the output, with cache enabled for both I and D:

```
Duration with 100 vmul, complex operands: 502 cycles
Duration with 100 vmul, simple operands: 499 cycles
Duration with 100 vmul, 0 operands: 406 cycles
```

As you can see there is a signifiant difference when an operand is 0, around -20%.

Comment: `vmul.f64 d2, d0, d1` That measures throughput, not latency.  A new `vmul` can start and read `d0, d1` while the previous one is still in flight, before it produces the `d2` result.

Comment: Also, I don't see how your `"r"` constraints ensure that the inputs will actually be in `d0` and `d1` specifically.  Also `"r"` is an integer register constraint, not FP.  In fact it makes the compiler do `vmov    r2, r3, d0` to get the bit-pattern into integer regs: that's why you had to use `noinline` to make your broken asm constraints happen to work.  https://godbolt.org/z/toVy68.  Use a `"+w"` constraint for `d` registers: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html.  But yes, using `noinline` means you did actually measure throughput with the inputs you intended to.

Comment: However it's plausible that latency is still fixed while throughput varies.  Or maybe the FP multiplier isn't pipelined and the whole CPU pipeline stalls waiting for the result.  (So throughput = latency).  Waiting for the result before even starting a new multiply makes it easy to avoid write-back conflicts.  I wouldn't be surprised for Cortex-M7, it's a pretty simple pipeline.

Comment: I didn't think about the difference between throughput and latency. However, I don't understand : " it's plausible that latency is still fixed while throughput varies". How can the throughput vary if the latency is fixed ? Especially with fixed operands and not access to memory ?

Comment: You can imagine a partially-pipelined FPU with enough stages for the worst-case `mul` latency (other than exceptions / assists for subnormals) that avoids write-back conflicts by fixing the latency of operations.  But it could be ready to start a new independent operation sooner or later, depending on how many cycles an instruction occupies the first pipeline stage for.  So simple operations could have better throughput but the same latency as more complex operations.  This only makes sense if there is some actual pipelined part of the execution unit that justifies extending the simple latency